# How can I use my oven to sanitize equipment

Tags: sanitation

I want to sanitize and dry off my plate chiller using my oven. What temperature do I need to set the oven to, and how long do I need to hold that temperatures for?

Comment: Why do that instead of recirculating boiling wort through it?

Comment: I don't have a pump, so recirculating isn't an option. Plus putting the chiller away sanitized and sealed up makes me feel better :)

Comment: This may seem obvious - but don't sanitise plastic bottles in your oven.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, you need to hold at least 160F for at least 10 min.

Comment: Sounds right. That's the temperature you sterilize milk at, anyhow, and in both cases, you're trying to kill lactobaccili.

Comment: Keep in mind too the very inner core needs to get to 160F before you start the timer.  It might not take all that long, but its important to note.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your oven, it's dry-heat which takes MUCH longer than what water or steam could accomplish.  For dry-heat sterilization:

```
338°F (170°C) 60 minutes
320°F (160°C) 120 minutes
302°F (150°C) 150 minutes
284°F (140°C) 180 minutes
250°F (121°C) 12 hours (Overnight)
```

Now, granted that's sterilization not sanitation, but once it comes out of the oven, it's exposed.

Comment: What's the difference between sterilization and sanitation, for the purposes of cleaning and storing equipment?